# Can one combine proper classes into a set?

Tags: logic, alternative-set-theories

Let's assume you have two non-set classes $C_1$ and $C_2$ of objects. (E.g., $C_i$ is the class of all algebras of some distinct signature $S_i$ for $i=1,2$.) Now, is there a reasonable variant of class logics and set theory where the class $\{C_1,C_2\}$ is (perhaps, under certain restrictions) a set containing exactly two members?

Comment: Usually (in theories which can talk about proper clases, like NBG and MK) a proper class is *by definition* a class which is not contained in another class. Hence the situation you describe cannot happen *by definition*.

Comment: I know Quine suggested the idea of a set theory in which "proper classes" could be a member of properly smaller classes, but I don't believe he (or anyone that I'm aware of) developed the idea.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you want the class $\{C_1,C_2\}$ to be a *set*? because that's what you wrote ! or it can be a non-set class? If you assert that it must be a set then this mean that you are asking for a theory where proper classes can be elements of sets, and perhaps also be subclasses of sets. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @user0 The theories I mentioned are [Von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) and [Morse–Kelley set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory).

Answer (score 1):

Matters largely depend on how you *define* set class and non-set class. For example lets take ZFC+ there exists exactly one [inaccessible cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal) $\kappa$. Now in this set theory name every object in it as *class*, and name any class that is equi-numerouse to an element of $V_{\kappa}$  as  *set*, and any class that is bigger than all elements of $V_{\kappa}$ to be a non-set class. Then you'll have a theory with your requirement.

Moreover, I think you can do that in [Ackermann's set theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#AckeSetTheo), without being involved with the assumption of existence of inaccessibles, so you remain within the strength of $ZFC$ over the realm of sets of this theory. You can easily upgrade the class comprehension axiom to a class separation axiom after [Muller's](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF), apply the same re-definitions given above [with $V$ instead of $V_{\kappa}$], and you'll get similar results.

This definition sets the size of a class as a definition cut-off criterion between what is a set and what is not.

Even a wilder approach is to define a class as non-set if and only if it is of inaccessible cardinality. So according to this definition you can even have sets having subclasses of them that are non-sets.